# I want to match anything not including '#' but yes including '\#'

Tags: regex, perl

I'm looking for a perl code line that may contain regexps and comments
i need to capture everything until a comment. so i want all characters until # but I AM INTERESTED in capturing #
for example, if the line was:

```
if ($line=/\#/) {  #captures lines with '#'
```

I want to capture:

```
if ($line=/\#/) {
```

Comment: What about `\\#`? What about `\\\#`? What about `\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\#`?

Comment: thanks.
can you explain?

Comment: note that # in a regex or double-quoted string doesn't need to be escaped (unless the /x flag is used); the above is equivalent to `if ($line=/#/) {` (which should also presumably be captured intact, as I would guess should `print qx#echo it is not that easy#`)

Answer (score 3):

Give this a try:

```
use PPI;
my $ppi = PPI::Document->new('source.pl');
my $source = '';
for my $token ( @{ $ppi->find("PPI::Token") } ) {
    last if $token->isa("PPI::Token::Comment");
    $source .= $token;
}
print $source;
```

This should handle pretty much everything except here-docs.  If you need to deal with those, start by copying PPI::Document::serialize and modify it to stop on the first comment.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
^(?:[^#]|(?<=\\)#)+
```

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?331tv)

This will match anything from the start of the string (`^`), that is not a # (`[^#]`) **OR**
 a # that is preceeded by a backslash (`(?<=\\)#`)

Comment: May be semantics but the regex doesn't _capture_ anything as it is surrounded by non-capturing parentheses: `(?:...)`. It does _match_ the string though. Think I need some more coffee to put me in a less pedantic mood. ;)

Comment: @IlyaSchenberger, that's a ["look-behind"](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#(?<=pattern)-\K) it means "only if preceded by a ..."